# Parse Error: Unacceptable Facebook application id

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

When I try to sign into my iOS app using Facebook, I get the following error:

[13451:7e0f] Error: Unacceptable Facebook application id. (Code: 251, Version: 1.2.19)

The strange part is that I only encounter this error when I make an adhoc build of my iOS app. Signing into my app via Facebook works fine for the debug configuration.

I did the following to ensure that there was no disparity between debug and adhoc configuration builds:

1. Bundle IDs for both the configurations are added to the Settings section for the app on developers.facebook.com
2. The FacebookAppId is the same for both the configurations.
3. The FacebookDisplayName is the same for both the configurations.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this error only in the adhoc configuration? I am using Cocoapods for the Facebook iOS SDK.

Answer (score 5):

have you added your Facebook App id on Parse.com . If you didn't then

- Login to parse.com
- Select **Your App** and Go to **Setting tab**
- In setting tab you will find **User Authentication**
- In UserAuthentication you will find **Facebook**

[image]

If here have no facebook Id then add here, and already exit then again add your facebook app setting. Hope you will got success bacause in my last project I also have same problem.

Comment: Yes, I have. That's why it works just fine in debug and production configurations but does not work in an adhoc build configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I double checked and the Facebook ID is not in sandbox mode. The Debug configuration of the app uses the same Facebook ID and works just fine.

Comment: ok, but I have also got same problem like this and I do have setup on parse.com and got success....